# I want to shorthand my code in using condition?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I did `$company` into new array according to its same `group` value.
In my real project `$company` array is more than that.So the `group` value has many ,then checking my **if else** condition code will be more need to write.I'll be appreciate if there is any good shortand code below that condition !!

```
<?php
$company = [["name"=>"Gnext","group"=>"Pro"],
            ["name"=>"AXN","group"=>"Standard"],["name"=>"Victim","group"=>"VIP"],
            ["name"=>"Necom","group"=>"Standard"],["name"=>"Mnet","group"=>"Pro"]
           ];
$new_arr = array();

foreach ($company as $key => $value) {
    if($value["group"] == "Pro"){
        $new_arr[$value["group"]][] = $value["name"];
    }
    elseif ($value["group"] == "VIP") {
        $new_arr[$value["group"]][] = $value["name"];
    }
    else{
        $new_arr[$value["group"]][] = $value["name"];
    }
}
var_dump($new_arr);
```

Comment: Uh, what? Your question is a tad confusing, but remember that readability is also a factor when coding, you might wanna use a switch?

Comment: output is no problem . Just desired to short my coding in if else condition when group value is more than 3 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the same in every if / else statement.. why dont you shorten this?

```
foreach ($company as $key => $value) {
  $new_arr[$value["group"]][] = $value["name"];
}
```